# Unable to set SOAP header with mustUnderstand

Tags: php, xml, soap

Following is the Request XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ISessionManager/Logon</Action>
<h:ContractVersion xmlns:h="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">330</h:ContractVersion>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<LogonRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService">
  <logonRequestData xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <d4p1:DomainCode>WWW</d4p1:DomainCode>
    <d4p1:AgentName>API****</d4p1:AgentName>
    <d4p1:Password>********</d4p1:Password>
    <d4p1:LocationCode i:nil="true" />
    <d4p1:RoleCode>APIB</d4p1:RoleCode>
    <d4p1:TerminalInfo i:nil="true" />
  </logonRequestData>
</LogonRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And following is my PHP code.

```
$test->DomainCode = 'WWW';
$test->AgentName = 'AGENT';
$test->Password = 'PASS';
$test->RoleCode = 'ROLE';

$wsdl = "https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/sessionmanager.svc?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));


$header = new SoapHeader('h','ContractVersion','330', '1');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

...

For the above code I get the following error.

> `SoapFault exception: [s:MustUnderstand] The header 'ContractVersion' from the namespace 'h' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed. This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process. Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding.`

How do I fix this issue? Since the WSDL can only be accessed from a specific IP i have given the link below

WSDL: http://pastie.org/9263788

Comment: Can you include a link to the XSD from this namespace: `https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc?xsd=xsd3` as well? It's not accessible from the WSDL and it declares the element you are having a problem with.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SOAP concept. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The URL above, which you can access locally, points to a file (a XSD schema). It is imported automatically by your WSDL. Inside it there is an element declaration for `ContractVersion`. If you can post that file as well, it may help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I think its visible in this link itself http://pastie.org/9263788

if this is not the one you are referring to then  i need to ask the API provider.

Comment: In that link you posted the *WSDL document*. That document contains this tag: `<xsd:import schemaLocation="https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices"/>` which refers to the XSD which describes the elements in the `http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices` namespace. There is no information in the link you posted about `ContractVersion`. That information is in the XSD.

Comment: It might not be necessary to see the XSD (if 300 is an accepted value). You were calling the `SoapHeader` incorrectly. See the answer.

Comment: I have updated my post. Check last part.

Comment: The error was caused by calling the `SoapHeader` incorrectly, as I explain un the answer. After that passed, you now have a new error with the `Logon` object. Create a new question about that error, and include all the information necessary about the `Logon` object (XSD) and the stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax, according to the [SOAPHeader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php) documentation, should be:

```
SoapHeader ( string $namespace , string $name , mixed $data , bool $mustunderstand )
```

In your code, you placed the *namespace prefix* where the namespace should be:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('h','ContractVersion','330', '1');
```

Change that line to:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices','ContractVersion','330', 'true');
```

Comment: That gave error SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php(19): SoapClient->__call('Logon', Array) #1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php(19): SoapClient->Logon(Object(stdClass)) #2 {main}error!

Comment: That error means that the header was understood, and the problem you placed in your question solved. What you have now is another problem that deserves another question. When you formulate the other question you should include the XSD for the `Logon` type, which is causing that error (you probably are not sending the data in the structure that is required by your `Logon` object)

Comment: Also, it seems that your `Logon` object expects an array. What that array should contain can be revealed by the XSD. Depending on your configuration you might be able to send login credentials when instantiating the `SoapClient`. In any case, that is another question.

Comment: Ah! Can you update your answer with the structure I need to send the data? I'm tired of trying different methods and exhausted... Or you can give me hints so that I may try.

Comment: I have no idea. Don't you have a documentation from the service? The XSD will describe the structure of the `Logon` object, but I can't guarantee it will be enough. There may be other details you might have to deal with. You should ask your provider for a sample application which connects to the service, and use it as a starting point.

Comment: They have just shown the request and response XMLs in the documentation. This is Tiger Airway API. They don't even support PHP. I got to get a sample code for Logon for c# and verify the request.